# dplyr select column from column A to column D and everything in between?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's use iris

```
> colnames(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

What I want is to select columns by giving the 2 extremities.
For example, all columns in between of Sepal.Length and Petal.Width, inclusive of the extremities.

```
iris %>% dplyr::select(Sepal.Length -- Petal.Width) 

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
....
```

Comment: `iris %>% dplyr::select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)` and base R `subset` works too `subset(iris, select = Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)`

Comment: You can also use column numbers, e.g. `iris %>% dplyr::select_at(.vars = 2:3)`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on ':' operator, my memory has been rusty lately as I had to switch to another language.